# Fix Low Quality Images in Open Classifieds

Tags: php, image

I'm running an older more reliable version of Open Classifieds (version 1.7.5.1) on my website. The problem I'm having is that user images are so low quality that they look artifact-ed or pixelated. I see this is not just a problem with the old version but the newer versions too. I don't know why the images look so terrible but I have reason to believe the problem lies within the resize.php class. I just need someone with more experience in PHP than me to look at the original file and look at the modifications I made to the new file and see what I'm missing. Or possibly the problem could be in another file. Please, Advise.

[Open Classifieds v 1.7.5.1 (Original)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69455950/Open_Classifieds_1.7.5.1.zip)

[revised resize.php class](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69455950/resize.txt)

Thanks in Advance!

-James

Comment: no offense, but i'm not comfortable downloading that zip file.  Can you post the relevant part of your front-end code?  I do see in "function size_height($size=100)" in revise.php, same for height and auto.  those are default settings to make the thumbnails 100px high and wide.  You could try increasing them.  I'm guessing resize.php compresses the image, then you output the thumbnail at 400x400 or something

Comment: @Ryan, The zip file is completely safe. It's located inside my DropBox, for easy access. I run Avast 8.x and Malwarebytes on my PC, so I'm pretty sure it's safe. The file is called 'resize.php' not revise.php, and is located in the includes/class directory of the script package. Please, if you don't feel comfortable downloading from my DropBox, search Google for Open Classifieds 1.7.5.1 download. I could really use the help.

Comment: no problem, may i visit your site to see the problem in action?

Comment: @Ryan, Sure but I want to PM it to you, because I don't want it public. How do I do that? Do you have a way I can contact you privately?

Comment: np - i also just visited the demo for OpenClassifieds, and their images are displayed as large as 650x650.  If there are only 100px in the original image, the browser will substitute 6x6 square blocks for each pixel -I'm sure that's what's going on.  Try changing those 3 values I mentioned to 300 and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

In `resize.php`, change:

```
function size_height($size=100)
function size_width($size=100)
function size_auto($size=100)
```

to

```
function size_height($size=300)
function size_width($size=300)
function size_auto($size=300)
```

Or some other larger value.  Keep in mind that larger image sizes will consume more resources and take longer to load, but experiment with different settings and find the right balance for your page.

Comment: [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69455950/business.jpg) is what an image looks like with sizes at 550 so I don't know if thats it. The original is [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69455950/business_original.jpg). Notice the discoloration also.

Comment: Is there a better way to process the image in PHP to get a better result? Can this PHP page be substituted with something more modern?

Comment: Your script there is using "GD" on the back end- You might want to research "ImageMagik" and have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158756/what-is-the-best-image-manipulation-library   -Sorry, I am close to limit of my knowledge on this topic, but you're on the right track - I agree that a more modern library may help.